# Can't get deoplete plugin working in Neovim

Tags: neovim, plugin-system

I have installed [deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim) plugin into my Neovim using [dein](https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim). I have put `let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1` into my `init.vim` and I can see the autocomplete list when I type in the insert mode - so far so good. However I am not able to autocomplete the word I am typing from the list which has appeared (I guess it should be done using Tab but none of the keys I tried worked). I am a Vim beginner so I am actually getting lost now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim uses `Ctrl-n` (next item) and `Ctrl-p` (previous item), `Ctrl-y` (accept match) or `Ctrl-e` (cancel) and so on for completion. See `:h ins-completion-menu` and `:h popupmenu-keys` for details.

The following `deoplete` settings may help (they use `Tab`, `Enter` and `Esc`) - see the comments for what they do:

```
"use <tab> for completion
function! TabWrap()
    if pumvisible()
        return "\<C-N>"
    elseif strpart( getline('.'), 0, col('.') - 1 ) =~ '^\s*$'
        return "\<tab>"
    elseif &omnifunc !~ ''
        return "\<C-X>\<C-O>"
    else
        return "\<C-N>"
    endif
endfunction

" power tab
imap <silent><expr><tab> TabWrap()

" Enter: complete&close popup if visible (so next Enter works); else: break undo
inoremap <silent><expr> <Cr> pumvisible() ?
            \ deoplete#mappings#close_popup() : "<C-g>u<Cr>"

" Ctrl-Space: summon FULL (synced) autocompletion
inoremap <silent><expr> <C-Space> deoplete#mappings#manual_complete()

" Escape: exit autocompletion, go to Normal mode
inoremap <silent><expr> <Esc> pumvisible() ? "<C-e><Esc>" : "<Esc>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the Supertab plugin (https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) let me use tab for deoplete completions, without needing any additional configuration.